# Write floating point numbers without any decimal places

Tags: python, string, format

I'm trying to have Python replicate some FORTRAN output of real values. My FORTRAN prints the real value as "31380.". I'm trying to replicate the same in Python--note that although I have no decimal places, I actually want the decimal point (period) to be printed. My current code is

```
htgm=31380.
print '{:6.0f}'.format(htgm)
```

which yields "31380". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about appending `.` in the format string? `'{:6.0f}.'.format(htgm)`

Answer (score 2):

Python format language includes an 'alternate' form for floats which forces the decimal point by using a '#' in the format string:

```
>>> htgm=31380.
>>> format(htgm, '#.0f')
'31380.'
```

Which is what I think you are looking for.
I thought `#g` would be what you wanted but for some reason python adds the `0` back on:

```
>>> htgm=31380.
>>> format(htgm, 'g')
'31380'
>>> format(htgm, '#g')
'31380.0'
```

Comment: is this only available in Python 3?

Comment: While the `#` has been around since Py >2.6 it looks like the alternate form for floats was only added in Py3.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it Python keeping the type of `htgm` as `float`. However if you are OK with making it as `str`, you may do:

```
htgm=31380.
'{0:.0f}.'.format(htgm)
# returns: '31380.'

# OR, even simply
'{}.'.format(int(htgm))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to display the number, use:

```
print(str(htgm)[:-1])
```

This notation will shave off the last '0'.